# Orthogonal transformation on $R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let T:$\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ be an orthogonal transformation such that det T=1 and T is not the identity. Let S subset of $\mathbb R^3$ be the Unit sphere. Show that T fixes exactly two points on S.

S is compact and the linear function T is continuous. Hence T(S) is compact. No way I can proceed further. Help me out please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fixed point problem for orthogonal transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200961/fixed-point-problem-for-orthogonal-transformation)

Comment: Thank you. Noted the answer from the reference given.